# Set an object to formControlName (dropdown)

Tags: angular

Im trying to implement an edit operation with reactive form in angular 7. I have to select a default value from select dropdown based on db call when bootstrap model opens. Once it automatically assigned, another dropdown also should be automatically filled based on the db call.

My problem is, I have to set an object within **[ngValue]**. The following code doesn't assign when the model opens.

But If I put

`[value]='depToBranch.company.id'` and `this.signupForm.get('company').patchValue(this.setEditUser.company.id);` its working (**Here I use *'id'* only, not object**).

> The only difference between two is that value is always string, where
>   in ngValue you can pass object

How can I assign the default value when model opens using object? Thanks in advance.

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<select formControlName="company" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedCompnay($event)">
    <option  *ngFor="let depToBranch of depToBranchs" [ngValue]="depToBranch.company">{{depToBranch.company.name}}</option>
</select>

<select formControlName="branch" (ngModelChange)="onSelectBranch($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let filterBranch of filterBranchs" [ngValue]="filterBranch.branch">{{filterBranch.branch.name}}</option>
</select>

// few other fields
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
@Input() setEditUser: User;
@Input() edit: boolean;
signupForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
            company: [""],
            branch: [""]
            //// few other fields
        })
    }

ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.edit){
        this.signupForm.get('company').patchValue(this.setEditUser.company);
        this.signupForm.get('branch').patchValue(this.setEditUser.branch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not setting the default value in `ngOnInit`? You could just declare defaulted form group controls -- something like `company: [this.setEditUser.company]` -- this way you won't have to rely on `patchValue`.

Comment: Actually im lising all. Then when i click esit button, the model will pop up. Im using the same model for adding and editing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to assing an object need to be sure is the same object,e.g.

```
items=[{company:1,branch:"..",...},{company:2,branch:"..",...}]
signupForm.controls.company.setValue(items.find(x=>x.company==1))

<select FormControlName="company">
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
</select>
{{singupForm.controls.company.value|json}}
```

But, try don't use (ngModelChange), just subscribe to changes after create the form if you need it

Answer (score -1):

I am new with angular. But I think you can't do this. the values of form control only accept primary values like numbers or strings.

Comment: No, Luciano,a FormControl can get anything

Comment: From my research "The only difference between value and ngValue is that value is always string, where in ngValue you can pass object"